# how can I link to a PlugIn admin-sub-menu page after processing a formular

Tags: plugins, redirect, admin-menu

I have a Plugin with 3 submenu_pages.
In one page is a formular (in one some text and in one a list of items). when I submit the form, there will be done some processing. after that I don't want to get back to the form-page, but WP shell redirect me to one of the other submenu_pages (in this case a list).

how can I achive this?

```
add_menu_page( 'page1 main page', '0', 'manage_options', 'mg-pi', 'mg_backend');    
add_submenu_page( 'mg-pi', 'list smthing', '0', 'manage_options', 'mg-pi-sub-list', 'mg_list');
add_submenu_page( 'mg-pi', 'create', '0', 'manage_options', 'mg-pi-sub-create', 'mg_new_item');
```

so in `mg_new_item()` is the processing and then it shell redirect to `mg_list()`. but if I do the php call to `mg_list()` the url is still the one of `mg_new_item()`.

I know I could do some `header("Location: the-hardcoded-list-url");` but I am looking for the WordPress common way of doing it, with generic Url generation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress PHP plugin - Settings page error](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106555/wordpress-php-plugin-settings-page-error)

Comment: I don't think it's a dublicate @s_ha_dum. But the answer might help sombody anyway. 

But my problem with it (that other answer) is, that it's not a redirect. If I use that solution, I will have to put the logical code of the formular to the list-code ... which I would like to avoid.

Additionaly I want to consider: That other Answer also is not accepted so far, and as you can read in the comments there are still problems with that solition.

Comment: You have not posted enough of your code for me to tell what you are doing, much less to try to debug and test.

Comment: Also, the answer is not accepted but it does work. I do this all the time. You cannot always account for other people's confusion.

Comment: There is nothing to debug so far. I am looking for a way to redirect to a sub-menu-page with a wordpress given function, where I get the Url maybe via the slug or something, like it is possible in theme templates as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after some more research I fond what I was actually looking for. Not for a workaround but for a wordpress compatible way.

There is a function called: `menu_page_url` which expects the defined slug.
and there is `wp_redirect`

so we have 2 wordpress functions to call. In this case:

```
$foo = menu_page_url("mg-pi-sub-list");
wp_redirect($foo);
```

that's it. And the good thing, I observe all Wordpress rules and the plugin will be compatible in future versions.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/menu_page_url

UPDATE

and if you have troubles with your headers you can help you out with this parameter:

```
<form action="?page=your-sub_page-slug&noheaders=true">
```

Comment: i think you should add second parameter too, as you no need to echo-ing the url. `$foo = menu_page_url("mg-pi-sub-list", false);`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `add_query_arg()`, `remove_query_arg()` and `get_query_var()`.

On your page link, you use a simple query var like `step=one`.

```
$query_arg = add_query_arg( 'step', 'one', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```

Then, when the user processed the form, you just reload the page. Then simply check if

```
0 !== get_query_var( 'step' )
AND 'one' !== get_query_var( 'step' )
```

and process further. If you want to go back, just use `remove_query_arg()`, etc.